# micronaut integration tests bean order

Tags: micronaut-client, micronaut-rabbitmq

I'm using Micornaut 3.7.4 and java 11.The server engine is netty. I use RabbitListener annotaion to retrieve messages from RabbitMQ. My producer and consumer are in the same application. I also injected http client to RabbitListener bean

```
@Inject
@Client("/")
private HttpClient httpClient;
```

In my consumer I call controllers of my application (http calls) (I know that I can call service methods) When I run my application everything works fine, but when I run test I get following error

```
at ali.qocayev.job.$DedicatedSequentialTaskHandler$Definition.injectBean(Unknown Source)
at ali.qocayev.job.$DedicatedSequentialTaskHandler$Definition.build(Unknown Source)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2354)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2305)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2879)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2800)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1680)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1655)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:878)
at io.micronaut.rabbitmq.intercept.RabbitMQConsumerAdvice.getExecutableMethodBean(RabbitMQConsumerAdvice.java:263)
at io.micronaut.rabbitmq.intercept.RabbitMQConsumerAdvice.process(RabbitMQConsumerAdvice.java:136)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.lambda$initializeContext$39(DefaultBeanContext.java:1996)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.lambda$initializeContext$40(DefaultBeanContext.java:1969)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1337)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1967)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.initializeContext(DefaultApplicationContext.java:249)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.readAllBeanDefinitionClasses(DefaultBeanContext.java:3326)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.finalizeConfiguration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3684)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.start(DefaultBeanContext.java:341)
at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:194)
at io.micronaut.test.extensions.AbstractMicronautExtension.startApplicationContext(AbstractMicronautExtension.java:433)
at io.micronaut.test.extensions.AbstractMicronautExtension.beforeClass(AbstractMicronautExtension.java:314)
at io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.MicronautJunit5Extension.beforeAll(MicronautJunit5Extension.java:84)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$12(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:395)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:395)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:211)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:84)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Retrieving the port from the server before it has started is not supported when binding to a random port
```

Does anybody know how to solve this issue? All my beans fail instantiating. I tried to play with bean creation order, but unsuccessfully

Comment: Does it build/test from the command line? `./mvnw package`|`./mvnw test` or `./gradlew build`|`./gradlew test`? Looking at the stack trace, namely `com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner` points to an IDE issue.

Comment: I get same result when I test from Intellij menu and run mvn test

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Retrieving the port from the server before it has started is not supported when binding to a random port